# Making "Null" as "" in JSON payload

Tags: apex, json, callout, null, serialization

I am trying to push a JSON input payload, but some fields might be blank.
The receiving system has a problem with it.
They want either the blank fields to not be sent all together or replace "Null" from JSON payload to "".
I was planning to do the latter...
I tried to use if-else condition to check if the field is blank and replace "Null" to "", but keep getting 500 Internal Error.

Incorrect Format ..

```
"displayName" : "Null",
```

Correct Format  ..

```
"displayName" : "",
```

Does any one know how can this be done. The below code didn't work as callout failed with Internal Error , Status Code 500.

```
@InvocableMethod
public static void postAccountToSystem(List<Id> acctIds){
Account acc = [SELECT Name,Display_Name__c,
                   Bio_URL__c,Image_URL__c
                    FROM Account WHERE Id = :acctIds[0]];  

    if(acc.Display_Name__c == NULL){
        acc.Display_Name__c = '';
    }

    if(acc.Bio_URL__c == NULL){
        acc.Bio_URL__c = '';
    }
    if(acc.Image_URL__c == NULL){
        acc.Image_URL__c = '';
    }

   String jsonInput = '{\n' +
        ' "displayName" : "'+acc.Display_Name__c+'",\n'+
        ' "bioUrl" : "'+acc.Bio_URL__c+'",\n'+
        ' "imageUrl" : "'+acc.Image_URL__c+'",\n'+
       System.enqueueJob(new QueueableCall(jsonInput, acc.Id));   
}
```

Comment: In JSON, null should be `null`, without quotes. And your system should be able to handle those values correctly if they're using a real JSON parsing library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should just serialize a `Map<String, String>`:

```
Map<String> data = new Map<String, String>
{
    'displayName' => acc.Display_Name__c,
    'bioUrl' => acc.Bio_URL__c,
    'imageUrl' => acc.Image_URL__c
};
String payload = JSON.serializePretty(data);
```

Comment: Hey Adrian.. I tried your approach , but two things are happening .. "Null" is becoming null and not ' '. Secondly , serializePretty is not removing null fields 
        Map<String, String> data = new Map<String, String>{
            'email' => acc.Email__c,
            'displayName' => acc.Display_Name__c,
      'bioUrl' => acc.Bio_URL__c,
      'imageUrl' => acc.Image_URL__c,
             };
        String jsonInput = JSON.serializePretty(data, True);
        System.enqueueJob(new QueueableSeleneCall(jsonInput, acc.Id));

Answer (score 0):

You could also put default value to empty string on those kinds of nullable text fields.

And use JSON.serialise() to turn account as a json string object